# How to default to collapased groups in a richfaces:extendedDataTable

Tags: richfaces

The default behavior for a richfaces:extendedDataTable with groups is to display all the groups in their expanded view. The user can then collapse them or expand them using the UI. How can the groups be displayed collapsed by default?

Comment: Hi

Did you ever implement a fix for this lliana?

Has anybody ever extended the extendedDataTable class to implement this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no supported way of doing this according to the RichFaces team.

http://community.jboss.org/message/539369#539369